# Data from loop is being displayed more times that I need it to

Tags: javascript, node.js, pvp.net-api

I'm making some requests to an API. It's from a game. First I'm doing a request to get an Id, then with that id I get a live match and what I'm pulling out are the the character that each person is playing along with the name of the player. I did this in Python as my first script but honestly I'm kinda confused with the approach in NodeJS.

The origin of the problem is that I'm doing a nested loop and well. It prints the whole data plus the champion that everyone is playing like 10 times.

This is part of the request code:

```
// SUMMONER ID TO FETCH DATA
request.get(`https://lan.api.pvp.net/api/lol/lan/v1.4/summoner/by-name/ronalxo?api_key=${riotKey}`, (err, resp, body) => {
    let parseBody = JSON.parse(body);

    let summonerID = parseBody.ronalxo.id;

    // LIVE GAME
    request.get(`https://lan.api.pvp.net/observer-mode/rest/consumer/getSpectatorGameInfo/LA1/${summonerID}?api_key=${riotKey}`, (err, resp, body) => {
        let parseBodyGameInfo = JSON.parse(body);
        let idsSeen = [];
        let championBeingPlayed = [];

        for (let t in parseBodyGameInfo.participants) {
            championBeingPlayed.push(parseBodyGameInfo.participants[t].championId);
        }

        //console.log(championBeingPlayed);

        // CHAMPION TO COMPARE ID WITH KEY AND SEE IF IT MATCHES THEN DISPLAY THE CHAMPION NAME
        // THIS IS A NESTED REQUEST
        request.get(`https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/lan/v1.2/champion?api_key=${riotKey}`, (err, resp, body) => {
        let parsechampionIds = JSON.parse(body);

            for (let x in parsechampionIds.data) {
                if (parsechampionIds.data.hasOwnProperty(x)) { // LOOKS FOR ID OF CHARACTER
                    let championId = parsechampionIds.data[x].id;

                    if (championBeingPlayed.indexOf(championId) !== -1 ) { // THE ID FROM ABOVE GETS MATCHED WITH OTHER IDS HERE TO DISPLAY OTHER DATA
                        for (var i in parseBodyGameInfo.participants) { // CHECKS FOR PARTICIPANTS ON MATCH
                            if (parseBodyGameInfo.participants[i].teamId === 100) { // CHECKS THE ID OF THE TEAM THAT THE PLAYER BELONGS TO
                                if (idsSeen.indexOf(parseBodyGameInfo.participants[i].teamId) === -1 ) { // CHECKS IF TEAM ID IS IN ARRAY
                                    console.log(`***** BLUE TEAM *****`); // I PUT THIS HERE SO IT DISPLAYS ONLY ONCE, NOT 10 TIMES
                                }

                                console.log(`${parseBodyGameInfo.participants[i].summonerName} playing ${parsechampionIds.data[x].name}`);
                            }
                            idsSeen.push(parseBodyGameInfo.participants[i].teamId); 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        });
    });
});
```

The output of that is something like this:

```
Anrez playing Thresh
I AM MIZUKAGE  playing Thresh
EriickX playing Thresh
xDBanned playing Thresh
yayobuenavibra playing Thresh
Anrez playing Cho'Gath
I AM MIZUKAGE  playing Cho'Gath
EriickX playing Cho'Gath
xDBanned playing Cho'Gath
yayobuenavibra playing Cho'Gath
Anrez playing Xin Zhao
I AM MIZUKAGE  playing Xin Zhao
EriickX playing Xin Zhao
xDBanned playing Xin Zhao
yayobuenavibra playing Xin Zhao
```

As you can see, it prints the same champion 5 times and because there are 10, it gets printed 10 times. Obviously this isn't the behaviour I want it to have. I want the output to be like:

```
Anrez playing 
I AM MIZUKAGE  playing Xin zhao
EriickX playing Thresh
xDBanned playing Cho gath
yayobuenavibra playing Tristana
Anrez playing Miss Fortune
```

Which are the name of the characters, so, I want to know where to place the *for loop* (besides a good refactor that I should do).

Comment: That is your server API response?

Comment: @Łukasz Yes, the data is being requested correctly, it's just that I think that the for loop shouldn't go there, I updated the code with the parent request.

Comment: Loops need some cleaning up to make it easier to understand (I think I see the problem though). For example, you say "for (let x in parsechampionIds.data ) { if (parsechampionIds.data.hasOwnProperty(x)... you are already iterating x in parsechampionIds.data. You don't have to do the property lookup; if x doesn't exist in parsechampionIds.data, this will never be true...and so on. I would say the problem is that this sort of confusion is causing this to fail (index never found), so it gets repeated over and over for all participants: idsSeen.indexOf(parseBodyGameInfo.participants[i].teamId

Comment: Hmm, excuse me @SamOnela What exactly do I have to update on _games.json_? Isn't it just the data from the live match?

Comment: Oh sorry, @SamOnela I was actually looking for matches on lolnexus and using their names. the summonerId was from a request to a summoner and getting their id. I re-updated the code again, sorry for the confusion. Where (in the code above) ronalxo is the summoner that I was using, you can get another summoner who is playing from [here](http://www.lolnexus.com/recent-games?filter-region=7). `summonerId` should be all lowercase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there is a missing check to match the *championId* of the outer *for* loop with the *championId*. Try adding the if statement below:

```
for (let i in parseBodyGameInfo.participants) { // CHECKS FOR PARTICIPANTS ON MATCH

    //▼▼▼ add this conditional to match the championIds  ▼▼▼  
    if (parseBodyGameInfo.participants[i].championId == championId) {
          if (parseBodyGameInfo.participants[i].teamId === 100) { // CHECKS THE ID OF THE TEAM THAT THE PLAYER BELONGS TO
              console.log('***** BLUE TEAM *****'); // I PUT THIS HERE SO IT DISPLAYS ONLY ONCE, NOT 10 TIMES
            }
            console.log(parseBodyGameInfo.participants[i].summonerName, ' playing ', parsechampionIds.data[x].name);
          }
          idsSeen.push(parseBodyGameInfo.participants[i].teamId);
     }
}
```

You can see a demonstration in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/a6mCGgZVlNWn6ppi44QK?p=preview) - the *console* statements are visible in the browser console.

Comment: Ah, I see, yes, I checked back and another check was missing, thanks for help and taking the time to recreate it.

Comment: This code would be a good candidate for [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I'll post it there soon.